# unable to update my post from react client to drf server side

Tags: javascript, reactjs, django-rest-framework, next.js, formik

i'm unable to perform a put request to my drf server side. the create component is working perfectly but the the update return invalid data(meaning the serialized data is not valid),

now i notice the issue is with the file(image and audio), i consoled the response and the file data is a path or type string so for me to avoid this error i'd have to update my file before sending request to the server, which is not necessary what if the user wants to only update their title or description?. please how can i resolve this if possible how can i convert the string file path to  a file object type of fetch request be for prefilling the fields?

please any idea to resolve this

UPDATE JS(GET request)

```
 const getSongGenre=async()=>{
        const token=localStorage.getItem('token')
        const res =await fetch(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/update/${param.id}`,{
            method:'GET',
            headers:{'Authorization':`Token ${token}`},
        })
        const data= await res.json()
        // const new_data=await res.blob()
        console.log(data)

        setSongGenre(data.genre)
        // const song=data.music.audio.split('/')
        // console.log(data.music.audio.split('/')[data.music.audio.split('/').length-1])
        
    


        setSongDetail({
            artist_name:data.music.artist_name,
            title:data.music.title,
            audioFile:data.music.audio,
            imageFile:data.music.image,
            description:data.music.description,
            genre:data.music.genre,
        })

      
        
        formik.setFieldValue('artist_name',data.music.artist_name)
        formik.setFieldValue('title',data.music.title)
        formik.setFieldValue('audio',data.music.audio)
        formik.setFieldValue('image',data.music.image)
        formik.setFieldValue('description',data.music.description)
        formik.setFieldValue('genre',data.music.genre)



    }
```

UPDATE JS(PUT request)

```
const formik=useFormik({

        initialValues:{
            artist_name:'',
            title:"",
            // audio:"",
            // image:"",
            description:"",
            genre:"",

        },
        
        validationSchema:Yup.object({
            artist_name:Yup.string().required(),
            title:Yup.string().required(),
            // audio:Yup.string().required(),
            

            }),
            
        
            onSubmit:((values)=>{
                const token=localStorage.getItem('token')
                // const data={
                //     artist_name:values.artist_name,
                //     title:values.title,
                //     audio: values.audio,
                //     image:values.image,
                //     description:values.description,
                //     genre:values.genre,
                 
                // }


                const data=new FormData()
                data.append('artist_name',values.artist_name)
                data.append('title',values.title)
                data.append('audio',values.audio)
                data.append('image',values.image)
                data.append('description',values.description)
                data.append('genre',values.genre)


                // console.log(typeof(values.audio))


                console.log(data)
                console.log(formik.values)
                fetch(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/update/${param.id}`,{
                    method:"PUT",
                    body:data,
                    headers:{
                        // "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                        // "Accept":"multipart/form-data",
                        // 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
                        'Authorization':`Token ${token}`,
                    },
                    
                }).then(res=>res.json())
                .then(data=>{
                    try{
                        console.log(data)
                        formik.setFieldValue('artist_name','')
                        formik.setFieldValue('title','')
                        formik.setFieldValue('audio','')
                        formik.setFieldValue('image','')
                        formik.setFieldValue('description','')
                        formik.setFieldValue('genre','')

                        if(data.status === false){
                            
                            document.getElementById('upload_msg').style.display='block'
                            document.getElementById('upload_msg').innerHTML=`<li style=color:red>${data.message}</li>`
    
                            setTimeout(()=>{
                                if(document.getElementById('upload_msg').style.display=='block'){
                                    document.getElementById('upload_msg').style.display='none'
                                    // document.getElementById('error_msg').style.transition='2s ease'
                                }
                            },10000)
                        }

                    }catch(error){
                        console.error(error)
                    }
                })
            }),
           
            
        })
```